# Database Error: There is no row at position 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, if-statement

I believe this question was asked several months back, but i believe my situation is different and the same rules may not apply.

Everytime I execute this method that same error pops up. There is no row at position 0. If I change [0] to [1] or [15]; There is no row at [1] and etc. Could this mean that my database isnt even connecting? Should I write some kind of if statement to determine to check if the rows are even there?

```
    public bool UpdateOrderToShipped(string order)
{
    orderNumber = order;
    string batch = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SuccessfulOrderBatch"];
    string statement = "UPDATE SOP10100 SET BACHNUMB = '"+ batch +"' WHERE SOPNUMBE = @SOPNUMBE";
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(statement, connectionPCI);
    comm.Parameters.Add("SOPNUMBE", orderNumber);
    try
    {
        comm.Connection.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        comm.Connection.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        comm.Connection.Close();
        KaplanFTP.errorMsg = "Database error: " + e.Message;
    }

    statement = "SELECT SOPTYPE FROM SOP10100 WHERE SOPNUMBE = @SOPNUMBE";
    comm.CommandText = statement;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    soptype = dt.Rows[0]["SOPTYPE"].ToString();    //errror here

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why is your method a bool? It only returns true

Comment: @Andre: one obvious reason is that in the future the catch is going to return a false so that the caller will know whether it has succeeded or not.

Comment: @Chris, this is OK in some methods, where you expect errors to happen. This doesn't seen to be the case.

Comment: Im sure this is an extremely easy question, but I am getting an error with the Length property,

        CS1061: 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Im sure I can find the answer, but just in case anyone would like to help.

Comment: @javasocute: Case sensitive names... Length, not length.

Comment: @Andre: I was just giving you an example. I think its reasonable and I'm not sure I follow your logic but there are always bits of personal preference in code. And especially on stack overflow where often problems come in code that is still being written and is therefore incomplete or we may only have a partial view on things.

Comment: @Chris sure, that's why I asked. I could be wrong, OP may had come up with a good reason for returning a bool in this method, and I would learn from it. Or I could be right, he may don't even realized it's a bad design, and he would learn from it. That's why we're here at Stack Overflow, right? :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is very simple ... it means that no results were returned from your query. You always have to code defensively and check to see if the Rows array has any items in it before trying to index into it. Something like:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    soptype = dt.Rows[0]["SOPTYPE"].ToString();
else
    somethingWentWrong();
```

Comment: Thank you. By the way "ds.Rows.Count" is true, not "Length".

Answer (score 1):

you might have data in the table but I think the connection closes after the first query. try opening the connection again. Also you have string concatenation in the first SQL query, which isn't a good practice. try using block instead of try.. catch, just for a better code. And as Joel suggested, use a check

Answer (score 1):

```js
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.rows.count; i++)
{
    // do something till rows in DT
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, then I realized that my first column was not integer-based. So when I edited the first I faced the same error.

So, my suggestion is either not to edit the first column or make the first column an ID column in which case you don't have to edit anything.