# NUnit test runner retruns no record however debug code returns a valid record

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I can find a row if I run in debug mode, however don't see the select query returns a record in NUnit test run. The code works fine if I run in debug mode one by one so there should be something related to the wait/timing. I've seen questions around the same but this is different due to the fact that it returns records in debug mode and not via NUnit test runner.

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException : There is no row at position 0.

```
public static DataTable GetAddressStatusOfDevice(string deviceId, string connectionString)
    {
        string commandText = "SELECT * FROM dbo.DeviceAddresses WHERE DeviceID = @ID;";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {                
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = deviceId;
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                var dt = new DataTable();
                //Thread.Sleep(3000);
                da.Fill(dt);                    
                return dt; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where's your unit test code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database Error: There is no row at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795066/database-error-there-is-no-row-at-position-0)

Comment: Hi Liam, please see below.                                                                                              public string getDBAddressStatus()
        {
            string deviceId = getDeviceId();            
            DataTable dbAddressStatusDt = Utilities.GetAddressStatusOfDevice(deviceId, _connectionString);            
            string dbStatus = (dbAddressStatusDt.Rows[0][8].ToString());
            Debug.Print("The current status of the device is " + dbStatus);
            return dbStatus;            
        }